# Error trying to apply a function for each item (List) in TransformedDStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have an issue with my code. I'm working with Spark Streaming and I listen a stream of data (tweets). Each tweet is represented by a list in which each item is a single word. I'd like to apply a function for each word with the Map function but it doesn't work. In fact, I obtain this error:

*Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

This is the portion of the code that cause this issue:

```
model = Word2VecModel.load(sc, "/home/davide/word2vec_models")

features_training = training.map(lambda tweet: filtering(tweet[0].split(" ")))

features_training = features_training.map(lambda tweet:[model.transform(word) for word in tweet])
```

The "filtering" function returns another list with a word for each item

Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: can you add the code which is causing this

Comment: @QuickSilver I've updated the question